# Removed Nodes with Nokogiri but now I have empty lines in my XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

How can I tighten up my xml to not have the empty lines after I removed some nodes from my xml document?

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri gives you the ability to fiddle with the text nodes, i.e., the content between nodes:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(
'<p>this
    <b>text to remove</b>
    text
</p>')
doc.at('b').remove
doc.at('p').text = doc.at('p').text.gsub(/\n\s*\n/, "\n")

puts doc.text
```

The carriage returns embedded in the HTML, generating separate lines in the file, are actually in the intervening text nodes. So, after stripping a tag, you'll end up with whitespace-separated "`\n`" characters in the text nodes. A quick `gsub` can clean those out.